# Getting wrong calculation of fields (SSRS Chart)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need some help with my SQL query.

I'm now building na SSRS Dashboard on which I have created an Chart to show % of all tickets which got score above 8 and below 7.

I wanted that the chart will show me the data dynamicaly.

When an user choose a Month or more the chart should show the % for each of the Month.

Because the Multivalue Parameter is coma divided I have created an procedure to fix the issue.

Below I have attached the procedure.

I saw that when the user choose only one Month the % is showed correct.

But If the user choose January and February in the multivalue parameter the query is showing wrong data.

It shows me like this.

```
SUMMARY MONTH NAME  MONTH   YEAR
67     January      1       2018
71     January      1       2018
63     January      1       2018
68     January      1       2018
70     February     2       2018
75     February     2       2018
67     February     2       2018
71     February     2       2018
```

Which is wrong there should be only 2 lines or records showed not 4.

I don't know how to fix this issue.

I'm new in SSRS and SQL any help appreciated.

Correct values which should be showed are:

```
67, January, 1, 2018 
71, February,2, 2018
```

Below the procedure.

```
ALTER Procedure dbo.Procedure1

--@MONTH varchar(50)

AS

BEGIN

create table ##temp ([SUMMARY] float,[MONTH NAME] Varchar (50),[MONTH] Varchar (50),[YEAR] INT)

--declare @MONTH VARCHAR(150) = '1,2',
--declare @var_MONTH varchar(50), @SUPPORT_GROUP varchar(50) = 'xxx_DACH'

declare @MONTH VARCHAR(150) = '1,2',

@var_MONTH varchar(50), @SUPPORT_GROUP varchar(50) = 'xxx_DACH'


SET @var_MONTH=Replace(@MONTH,',',''',''')

print @var_MONTH

Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL ='

SELECT ROUND (100*(T2.[FCRR]-T1.[FCRR])/T3.[FCRR],0) AS [SUMMARY], T1.[MONTH_NAME] as [MONTH NAME], T1.[MONTH_NUMBER] as [MONTH], T1.[YEARS] as [YEAR]

FROM

--DETRACTORS
    (SELECT cast(count(*) AS FLOAT) AS [FCRR]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
        ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    FROM dbo.[PL_Survey]
    WHERE MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) IN ('''+@var_MONTH+''') and [QUESTION_3_SCORE] <7 AND SUPPORT_GROUP IN ('''+@SUPPORT_GROUP+''')
    GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])) AS T1,


 --PROMOTORS 
      (SELECT cast(count(*) AS FLOAT) AS [FCRR]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
        ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    FROM dbo.[PL_Survey]
    WHERE MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) IN ('''+@var_MONTH+''') AND SUPPORT_GROUP IN ('''+@SUPPORT_GROUP+''') and [QUESTION_3_SCORE] > 8
    GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])) AS T2,


--CASES COUNT
      (SELECT cast(count(*) AS FLOAT) AS [FCRR]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
        ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    FROM dbo.[PL_Survey]
    WHERE MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) IN ('''+@var_MONTH+''')
    GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])) AS T3'

Print @SQL


Execute( @SQL )

Select * From ##Temp

drop table ##Temp

END


--Execute dbo.Procedure1 '1,2'
```

Comment: Without some details to work with this is nearly impossible to help. Here is a great article discussing what information you should post. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the issue.

I had wrong query.

here the solution:)

```
ALTER Procedure dbo.Procedure1

@MONTH varchar(50)

AS

BEGIN

create table ##temp ([SUMMARY] float,[MONTH NAME] Varchar (50),[MONTH] Varchar (50),[YEAR] INT)

declare @var_MONTH varchar(50), @SUPPORT_GROUP varchar(50) = 'xxx_DACH'

--declare @MONTH VARCHAR(150) = '1,2',

--@var_MONTH varchar(50), @SUPPORT_GROUP varchar(50) = 'xxx_DACH'


SET @var_MONTH=Replace(@MONTH,',',''',''')

--print @var_MONTH

Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL ='

SELECT cast (100* (tt.[PROMOTORS] - tt.[DETRACTORS]) / tt.[CASES COUNT] as float) as [Summary], [MONTH_NAME] as [MONTH NAME], [MONTH_NUMBER] AS [MONTH], [YEARS] AS [YEAR]
FROM 

(SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
    ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
    ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN SUPPORT_GROUP IN ('''+@SUPPORT_GROUP+''') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [CASES COUNT]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [QUESTION_3_SCORE] < 7 AND SUPPORT_GROUP IN ('''+@SUPPORT_GROUP+''') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [DETRACTORS]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [QUESTION_3_SCORE] > 8 AND SUPPORT_GROUP IN ('''+@SUPPORT_GROUP+''') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [PROMOTORS]
FROM 
    dbo.[PL_Survey]
WHERE 
    MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) IN ('''+@var_MONTH+''') AND SUPPORT_GROUP IN ('''+@SUPPORT_GROUP+''')  
 GROUP BY 
    MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED])
    ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
    ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])) as tt'

Print @SQL


Execute( @SQL )

Select * From ##Temp

drop table ##Temp

END


--Execute dbo.Procedure1 '1,2'
```

Now my SSRS is working :)